# How to print a 2d character array C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I've made a 2D 8x8 array of ?'s. The code compiles with only one error "Unused variable 'grid'" which doesn't make since to me since I'm passing the grid into each method. However, I don't have my printed 8x8 grid of ?'s.

```
//  main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//Declare global variables
const int ROWS = 8; //initialize number of rows
const int COLS = 8; //initialize number of columns
int guesses = 5; //Holds number of palyer's guesses



int main()
{

    char grid[ROWS][COLS];

    int buildGrid(char grid);
    void displayGrid(char grid);

}
int buildGrid (char grid[COLS][ROWS]) {

    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {

        for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
            grid[col][row] = '?';
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
void displayGrid (char grid[COLS][ROWS]) {
    int row, col;

    //print  multiplication table
    for (row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
    {
        // prints columns for my row
        for (col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
        {
            cout << setw(3) << grid[row][col];

        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're confusing function declaration and function call.  You should forward declare the function before main (as opposed to in main) and then call it main.  Like so:

```
int buildGrid(char grid[COLS][ROWS]);
void displayGrid(char grid[COLS][ROWS]);

int main()
{

    char grid[ROWS][COLS];
    buildGrid(grid);
    displayGrid(grid);
}
```